# " Syntax error near unexpected token `636' "

Tags: c, shell, syntax

After compiling with:

```
gcc Lab10.c -Wall -Werror
```

I execute as:

```
./a.out (636)394-6659
```

I get the error: " Syntax error near unexpected token `636' "

Please note, that the Main function was provided as a skeleton for this, I did not write it.
I'm not concerned with optimizing logic, I can figure that out on my own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

/*
   Parameters
   token - A string

    Return:
    1 if the string is a valid phone number,
    0 otherwise

    A valid phone number takes the form
    (xxx)xxx-xxxx where x is a digit 0-9

*/

int isPhoneNumber(char* token);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    //This is a valid phone number
    assert(isPhoneNumber("(123)456-7890") == 1);

    //These are not valid phone numbers
    assert(isPhoneNumber("123-456-7890") == 0);
    assert(isPhoneNumber("1234567890") == 0);
    assert(isPhoneNumber("(123) 456-7890") == 0);
    assert(isPhoneNumber("Hello World") == 0);
    assert(isPhoneNumber("") == 0);

    printf("Congratulations! You finished the prelab!");
    return 0;
}

int isPhoneNumber(char* token)
{
    int i, digit;
    char leftBrack [2], rightBrack [2], dash[2];
    strcpy(leftBrack, "(");
    strcpy(rightBrack, ")");
    strcpy(dash, "-");
    for (i=1;i<14;i++)
    {
        if (i == 1 &&(strcmp(token, leftBrack) != 0))
            return 0;
        if (i > 1 || i < 5)
        {
            digit = atoi(token);
            if (digit < 0 || digit > 9)
            return 0;
        }
        if (i == 5 && (strcmp(token,rightBrack) != 0))
           return 0;
        if (i > 5 || i <9)
        {
            digit = atoi(token);
            if (digit < 0 || digit > 9)
                return 0;
        }
        if (i == 9 && (strcmp(token, dash) != 0))
        return 0;   
        if (i > 9 || i < 14)
        {
            digit = atoi(token);
            if (digit < 0 || digit > 9)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Your code is currently ignoring arguments. It doesn't matter what you give it on the command-line; it's working off a small, hardcoded group of phone numbers.

Comment: @computerfreaker Thank you kindly, I had a suspicion as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute this way:

```
./a.out "(636)394-6659"
```

Or as you don't check arguments, this way is the same:

```
./a.out
```

You don't use `argc` or `argv`, so use this prototype for `main()`

```
int main()
```

Also, you need to consider string a null terminated arrays of chars.

```
char leftBrack [2], rightBrack [2], dash[2];
```

`strcmp()` does not do what you believe it does. You need to use `strncmp` with a third argument equal to 1. Also `atoi()` checks the whole string, not a mere character, just check `token[i] - '0'` is a number between 0 and 9.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

/*
   Parameters
   token - A string

    Return:
    1 if the string is a valid phone number,
    0 otherwise

    A valid phone number takes the form
    (xxx)xxx-xxxx where x is a digit 0-9

*/

int isPhoneNumber(char* token);

int main()
{ 
    //This is a valid phone number
    assert(isPhoneNumber("(123)456-7890") == 1);

    //These are not valid phone numbers
    assert(isPhoneNumber("123-456-7890") == 0);
    assert(isPhoneNumber("1234567890") == 0);
    assert(isPhoneNumber("(123) 456-7890") == 0);
    assert(isPhoneNumber("Hello World") == 0);
    assert(isPhoneNumber("") == 0);

    printf("Congratulations! You finished the prelab!");
    return 0;
}

int isPhoneNumber(char* token)
{
    int i, digit;
    char leftBrack [2], rightBrack [2], dash[2];
    strcpy(leftBrack, "(");
    strcpy(rightBrack, ")");
    strcpy(dash, "-");
    for (i=0;i<14;i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 0:
            if (strncmp(token + i, leftBrack, 1) != 0)
                return 0;
            break;

        case 4:
            if (strncmp(token + i, rightBrack, 1) != 0)
                return 0;
            break;

        case 8:
            if (strncmp(token + i, dash, 1) != 0)
                return 0;
            break;

        case 13:
            if (strcmp(token + i, "") != 0)
                return 0;
            break;
        default:
            digit = token[i] - '0';
            if (digit < 0 || digit > 9)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Edit: Explaining what is token[0] - '0'.
If you put chars in a an arithmetic expression, they are converted in int values (implicitly casted as int), and the value is their ascii codes. Figures have [consecutive ascii codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) So `'0' - '0'` is `0`, `'1' - '0'` is `1` and so on. And as ascii codes are unique for each character, you are sure than no other character will have its ascii code between those of '0' and '9'. So if `c` is not a figure, you will have either `c < '0'` or `c > '9'` which is the same as `c - '0' < 0` or `c - '0' > 9`.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to have gotten past the previous error. Though I did do my own research, I do not have a clear understand of "assert." (Again, it was provided code).
When I run the program in the given way, I am getting:
"Assertion `isPhoneNumber("(123)456-7890") == 1' failed. Aborted"

Does this merely mean my parsing logic is incorrect?

Comment: @BCSullivan I have a runtime error, still trying to figure out what else is wrong with your code...

Comment: The thing is that you pass whole token to `strcmp` and it will never `return 0`, unless the token equals to a single character `(`.

Use something like this `if ( token[0] != '(' ) { return 0; }` instead.

Comment: @jdarthenay Very much so, the time is highly appreciated. Much more concise than my logic. However, if you don't mind, the only thing I am not grasping is the line after default:

digit = token[i] - '0';

What is the " - '0' " portion used for?

Comment: @BCSullivan Well, that's because chars are identical to their ascii codes.

Comment: @BCSullivan There is an error left, we don't check the last element is a null character, so a string such as "(636)394-6659toto" will be recognized as a phone number...

Comment: @jdarthenay Thank you. I implemented that after viewing your logic with a strlen implementation. Thank you so much for your time

Comment: @jdarthenay, After trying time and time again, I dont understand why we must do the " - '0' ". What is this accomplishing, and why must we have it?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to take command-line arguments, you have to actually provide the code to do so. Right now, your code isn't handling anything but a hard-coded group of phone numbers, making whatever you pass it irrelevant.

`argv` holds the arguments you've received, including the program's filename (which is always in `argv[0]`. `argc` tells you how many arguments you've received. You can use these values together like this:

```
//argc == 1 means we just got the filename, no actual arguments.
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
  assert(isPhoneNumber(argv[i]));
}
```